# Battleship | garbage printouts from char array

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am working on the Battleship game and I am trying to make a character array for the gameboard. What I am having in mind is a rectangular array of size 11x21. Something like this,

```
0  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 / 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
2  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
3  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
4  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
5  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
6  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
7  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
8  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
9  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
10 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```

What I'm trying to do is to have separate arrays later and mirror the history into that board and print it out into a log file.

The problem is right now I am stuck at initializing this 11x21 board. For some reason, the board is initialized up until row 6, i.e. the first value at gameboard[6][0] = 6.

Then after that, starting from row 7, the first value at gameboard[7][0] becomes a letter.

[image: Something like this:]

I suspect the letters messed with data and then caused the print to be garbage. But I am not sure where exactly that I went wrong.

Here is the original code:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
    char gameboard[11][22] = {'\0'};

    for (i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
    {
        gameboard[i][0] = (char)i;
        gameboard[i][11] = (char)i;
        for (j = 1; j < 11; ++j)
        {
            gameboard[i][j] = '~';
            gameboard[i][j + 11] = '~';
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 22; j++)
            printf(" %c", gameboard[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: Those letters are the Alarm, Backspace, Tab, and Newline characters. You shouldn't put the row and column numbers in the array. Or if you do put them in the array, you need to print them with `%d`, not `%c`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that but it still printed out garbage for the 0th row and 0th column.

@user3386109: thanks! I think I understand what you mean. I went back and change %c to %s and it prints out the correct values. Now I just need to figure out how to print the index row and column separately from the content rows and columns.

Comment: @user3386109 Oops yes, missed that.  But, they're initialized to `i`, rather than printable characters.  Isn't that the problem OP reports?

Comment: @TomKarzes Yup, that is the problem. The screenshot shows the actual number followed by an alternative representation, e.g. `6 '\x6'` and `7 '\a'`. OP was expecting `7 '\x7'`, without realizing that `\a` *is* 7. So those entries in the array cannot be printed with `%c`. They need to be printed with `%d`. Or better yet, they shouldn't be in the array in the first place. The code should print the row and columns separately from the contents of the array.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, I wouldn't try to keep those values in a `char` array, mixed with actual characters.

Comment: Thank you both. That makes much more sense now. I will have separate arrays for the row and column labels.

Answer (score 2):

When using characters array, don't try mixing it with integer values. These integer values will be interpreted as their character equivalents. [Here](http://www.asciitable.com/) is a chart that maps integer values to the characters that they represent. Instead of doing this, try to rely on the indices in the array to determine the row/col numbers.

This following code produces this as an output:

```
0  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 /1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
2  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
3  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
4  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
5  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
6  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
7  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
8  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
9  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
10 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ / ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
char gameboard[10][21];

for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        gameboard[i][j] = '~';
        gameboard[i][j + 11] = '~';
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    gameboard[i][10] = '/';
}

printf("0  ");
for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    j = i < 11 ? i+1 : i - 10;
    if (i == 10)
        printf("/");
    else {
        printf("%d ", j);
    }
}
printf("\n");

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d", i + 1);
    if (i + 1 <= 9)
        printf(" ");

    for (j = 0; j < 21; j++)
        printf(" %c", gameboard[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```